# Использование интерфейсов в приложении ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Изучаю архитектуру приложений на примере asp.net mvc. Изучаю по сайту metanit. И там в примере про onion архитектуру в контроллере создаётся экземпляр интерфейса репозитория.
Вот код с метанита:

```
IBookRepository repo;
IOrder order;
public HomeController(IBookRepository r, IOrder o)
{
    repo = r;
    order = o;
}
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var books = repo.GetBookList();
    return View();
}
```

Но ведь с таким же успехом можно создать экземпляр самого репозитория(экземпляр класса) и будет тот же самый результат:

```
BookRepository repo;
Order order;
public HomeController(BookRepository r, Order o)
{
    repo = r;
    order = o;
}
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var books = repo.GetBookList();
    return View();
}
```

В чём же тогда разница?? Создавать экземпляр класса или экземпляр интерфейса. Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Вопрос сводится к "для чего нужны интерфейсы", посмотрите, устроит ли вас один из [ранее заданных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC+%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8B) вопросов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для нужд вашего приложения *на текущем уровне* — никакой разницы. "Если это крякает как утка и плавает как утка — то это и есть утка".

Это будет иметь важное значение, когда вам нужно реализовать иное поведение. Тогда вы делаете новый класс, реализующий тот же интерфейс — и во всех местах, где вы закладывались на использование класса с некоторым интерфейсом вы сможете использовать любой класс, реализующий интерфейс.

Одно из самых типичных применений в приложениях — для целей юнит-тестирования.

В тесте вы создаёте контроллер, но передаёте не настоящий репозиторий, который умеет обращаться к настоящей базе — а некоторый класс, который умеет "прикидываться" для вашего контроллера репозиторием.

Например, вы можете считать репозиторием книг нечто, умеющее отдавать список книг:

```
public interface IBookRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Book> List();
}
```

И в проекте с тестами создать простую реализацию:

```
public class TestBookRepository : IBookRepository
{
    public TestBookRepository()
    {
        this.Books = new List<Book>()
        {
            new Book { Id = 1, Title = "книга 1" },
            new Book { Id = 2, Title = "книга 2" },
        }
    }

    private List<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Book> List()
    {
        return this.Books;
    }
}
```

Существуют библиотеки тестирования, которые могут автоматически создавать подобные заглушки, но и им нужно знать, какой интерфейс они "мокают".

И в тестах проверять методы вашего контроллера используя тестовый класс.

```
[TestFixture]
public class BooksControllerTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Index_Always_ReturnsAllRecords()
    {
        // Arrange
        var booksRepository = new TestBookRepository();
        var controller = new BooksController(booksRepository);

        // Act
        var result = controller.Index();

        // Assert
        // например проверить что число записей равно двум и их конкретное содержимое
    }
}
```

Сделать подобное, если вы используете имя конкретного класса либо невозможно, либо влечёт чрезмерное и ненужное усложнение этого класса. Также при помощи специализированных фреймворков вы можете быть уверенными, что запускается определённый метод и гарантируете это в тесте и т.п.

---

Пример для вопроса, заданного в комментариях:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new A();
    var b = new B();

    //this.Test(a);
    //this.Test(b);
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class A : IBookRepository
{
    public void GetById(int id) {}
}

public class B
{
    public void GetById(int id) {}
}

public void Test(IBookRepository my) {}

public interface IBookRepository
{
    void GetById(int id);
}
```

Comment: AK спасибо за ответ. Да я знаком с модульным тестированием немного. Использовал библиотеку риномок. Мне просто было интересно как работает этот механизм, всмысле что создаёшь экземпляр интерфейса, а в итоге у тебя всё равно экземпляр класса. Я так понимаю я могу этому интерфейсу передать экземпляр любого класса наследованного от этого интерфейса? А что если например класс имеет всю реализацию этого интерфейса с точно такими же названиями методов, но наследования от интерфейса нет. В таком случае этот интерфейс приме экземпляр такого класса? Но скорее всего вы скажите что такое нужно пробовать)

Comment: Не обязательно попробовать. Можно просто открыть любой букварь по c# и почитать раздел про интерфейсы, явную и неявную реализацию, перечитать раздел про приведение типов  -- но после этого уметь решать примеры на онлайн-тестах, собеседованиях или в голове или прорешать некоторое количество, чтобы закрепить теорию. Привёл пример в вопросе попробуйте угадать, что будет при запуске `this.Test(b)`? )) Приучите себя писать такие короткие скетчи на каждый вопрос, который вам придёт в голову, а также читать книги - и вы скоро увидите резкий рост вашего знания c#.

Comment: AK, то же самое что и если передать a? Произойдёт неявная реализация без наследования?

Comment: Хотя сейчас попробовал этот пример сделать, пишет что не может привести тип. Значит всё же ошибка. Необходимо будет приводить

Comment: Спасибо за ответ